# horizontal bar slider

Tags: android

I am looking for a class that implement a horizontal slider bar like the one on the "lock" screen.  In other words, user must slide the bar from left to right to run an activity.  Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Android uses a class called [`SlidingTab`](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/widget/SlidingTab.java.html) for this (the main lockscreen is in a file called `LockScreen.java`. As with all Android core code, it's Apache licensed. At the risk of sounding like a broken record here on SO, [download the AOSP](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) and read through the code whenever you have a "how did the Google folks do x?" type of question (or even when you don't; there's some good stuff in there).

Comment: Thank you Yoni. I'm just a beginner, so I am looking to do something simple :). Reading through the whole AOSP is something I dont think I can digest as I am trying to take one small step at a time. Why do you think Google people don't have this "SlidingTab" as a View for programmer to use?  Something as common and as simple as this slider should be a View (button, textview, edittext, etc.)  so we can use it without having to code much :).  Hopefully they will include this in the upcoming Android 3.0. BTW, if they have this class in the core OS, I guess I can call it from within my java files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [Seek Bar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) might help you towards a solution to your problem. If this works for you let me know, because i am interested in a solution to that as well. Thanks

The link is the developer document for that feature.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  That was what I found too, but I was hoping for a simpler class since basically all the slider does is to make sure the user slide it.  I guess I have to work with the Seek Bar until someone let me know a better/simpler way for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/custom-view-horizontalslider) is an example that extends a horizontal `ProgressBar` so that the user can set the "progress" by sliding left/right. It's actually quite straight forward, it just overrides the `onTouchEvent()` method, does some minor mathematics and sets the progress value depending on the `TouchEvent`'s X coordinate.